# How to plot figure in new ouput window, rather than on old window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, overlap

So I have a Jupyter Notebook with two plots. When I try to plot a third plot on a new output window when I run the code (just like the previous 2), it instead plots it onto the 2nd output plot window I made, and they overlap each other.
How can I make it plot in its own output area?

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new figure.

Comment: wow, it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `subplot` as well.

Here is a sample of what you can do:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #ploting library

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
fig.suptitle('My First Subplot', fontsize=21, fontweight='bold')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(7, 7, (1,17)) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(7, 7, (5, 21))
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(7, 7, (29, 45))

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = df1*2
df3 = df1**2

df1.plot(ax=ax1)
df2.plot.bar(ax=ax2)
df3.plot(ax=ax3)
```

outpout:

[image]